# Trackpad on Late 2016 MBP Stops Working When USB Gamepad Is Attached or ControllerMate Is Running

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, trackpad

I have been user [ControllerMate](https://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/) to optimize my workflow when using an external keyboard to trigger macros with [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/).

This worked very well until recently, when I installed an update for ControllerMate.

Now, when ControllerMate is running, the built-in trackpad of my MacBook Pro (late 2016) stops working. When I quit the application, the trackpad is functional again.

I thought it was an issue with ControllerMate, so I [posted on their support forum](http://www.orderedbytes.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=11440#11440), so far without any useful feedback.

Then I noticed that the same thing – non-functional trackpad – happens when I attach a gamepad controller via USB ([GameSir G3](https://gamesir.hk/?p=1&a=view&r=9)).

**Can somebody give me advice how to troubleshoot and perhaps find a fix for this problem?**

Comment: Did you check the setting in System Preferences > Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad > Ignore built-in trackpad when mouse or wireless trackpad is present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed**

The problem was that apparently installing the new version of ControllerMate somehow checked the preference “System Preferences > Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad > Ignore built-in trackpad when mouse or wireless trackpad is present”. I turned it off again and everything works fine now.

Thanks @toma for pointing it out in the comments!

Comment: This solution worked for me as well. I was hooking up an Xbox Controller (Via USB or Bluetooth) and the trackpad kept randomly shutting off.